# Is there a way to pass functions into views as optional parameters?

Tags: swift, swiftui, parameters, syntax

I am making an application in SwiftUI that involves answering yes or no questions. Because of this I have created a subview call YesOrNoView. This subview has two buttons, one labeled yes and the other labeled no. The view accepts a binding variable of question that returns true or false based on the users answer. It also accepts a binding variable of questionsAnswered and increments it whenever either button is pressed. This behavior works for most questions in the game, but for the final question I want it to execute custom logic to take the user to a different view. To do this I am trying to make the view accept a custom action/method that I can call from either buttons action logic. Ideally, the action would also be optional so that I don't have to pass it in the 99% percent of the time when I'm not using it.

**How do I pass a function as an optional parameter into a view and then run that action when a button within said view is pressed?**

I tried adding actions using

```
struct YesOrNoView<Content: Action>: View {
```

...
but it couldn't find action or Action within it's scope.

I also tried using

```
struct YesOrNoView<Content>: View {
```

But I got an error saying that the Content variables type could not be inferred.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the easiest would be to pass in another bool that defines whether it is the last question or not.

Comment: Generics has nothing to do with passing a function, create an optional property that holds the function and inject it using an `init` method

Comment: That is what I'm trying to do. I just can't find the correct documentation to show how to do it. Could you please show how in an answer and show the code Joakim? Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it working. Thanks for the help. If you'd like to post this as an answer I can mark it as having solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It return clickAction back to the view

```
 struct GenericButton<Title: StringProtocol>: View {

    let title: Title
    let action: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: action) {
                Text(title)
            }.frame(width: 200, height: 40)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
GenericButton("Button") {
// Button tapped action
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I managed to figure it out with help from @JoakimDanielson. The trick is to pass in an empty function as the default.

```
var myFunction: () -> Void = {}
```

Thanks for the help everyone.